# Submitting apps for ios5 or above?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios6

I've recently submitted an app to the app store for ios6 only, since going live I now have people asking to support ios5 now! Can someone advise how this can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the deployment target to iOS 5 and build for it. Assuming you aren't building against any iOS 6 only API's, you should be good to go. If you are using anything iOS 6 only (auto-layout, etc) you will have to revert those before submitting.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Bill. Unfortunately I'm using Auto-Layout, Social/Accounts frameworks and the new FacebookSDK for iOS6, I guess I'm going to be busy!

Comment: Yeah, that is unfortunate. It really stinks if you plan for iOS 6 and have to drop down to iOS 5. Good luck!